# Reduce grid width using matplotlib and saving as SVG or PDF

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, svg, png

To generate a PDF with high-quality images, I saved my matplotlib plots in vectorial formats such as SVG and PDF. However, when I embedded the images in my LaTeX document, the grid appeared wider than desired.

For instance, I want the grid to look like this:
[Grid I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyq1e.png).

This is how the image appears in the PDF without zooming:
[Grid once rendered the PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uiclu.png).

My question is if is there a way to display a thin grid, like in the first image, even if the image is too small for the grid to be visible.

I attempted to save the image in PNG format, which worked satisfactorily. However, upon zooming in, the image quality appeared to be subpar. Thus, my primary choice would be to use vector formats. If that is not feasible, then I would resort to PNG.

Comment: What does it look like in an independent image viewer? Your options might be to make the grid lines some shade of grey if it won't let you make them any thinner.

Comment: @MartinBrown I had not considered that solution. Although it was not what I was initially seeking, I believe it may be worthwhile for me. Thank you!